# High load and iowait on MySQL database server leads to slow MySQL INSERTS

Tags: mysql, performance, hard-drive

I have a MySQL database server runnuing on Ubuntu 12.10 with 64GB RAM, 2x3 TB SATA 6 Gb/s HDD 7200 rpm and software RAID 1 and an Intel Core i7-3930K.
The database server is accessed over a local network with a dedicated 1 GBit ethernet card.
The database is around 50 GB big and is the master in a replication setup.

IMO, there are two problems that lead to slow MySQL querying:

1. The load is *always* relatively high (>2) even when the db server is idle (it's not a big problem since the processor has 12 cores but it doesn't seem right)
2. `top` shows that around 95% of the system is idle, <1% is used **5%** is waiting (see following screenshot)

[image]

`iotop --only` shows that most of the disk IO is produced by jdb2/md2-8 and not mysqld - so mysqld shouldn't be the problem - but why is jdb2/md2-8 using up so many ressources? [image]

`cat /proc/mdstat` outputs the following:
[image]

My questions are:
**What causes the slow MySQL performance?

Is it the iowait? What causes the iowait?

Is it the RAID 1 - Is it the used harddisk?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a log-heavy database on just about the slowest disks out there. The reason you're seeing jdb2 on such high iowaits is because it's having a hard time keeping up writing the ext4 journals to disk

Either change disks to something that can keep up (SSD's come to mind, allthough regular SAS disks with a battery cache would work) and/or start tuning stuff. There are *plenty* of documentation out there when it comes to filesystem tuning in SQL environments.

A good starting point is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/disk-issues.html

Comment: would `hdparm -m 16 -d 1` work for SSD as well?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue after upgrading to MySQL 5.7.

Setting "sync_binlog=0" fixed it for me. MySQL had changed the default from 0 to 1 in 5.7.

Comment: Not sure that enabling "throw all my transactions away in the event of a crash" is a great thing to be advocating, in the general case.